# Question of Jordan Decomposition Proof in Artin's Algebra Book

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form

[image]

Can someone tell me why we can assume that the chains of subspaces become constant for large $r$ ?

It is page 122 of the 2nd edition of the book

Here is also a pdf file:

[http://home.ustc.edu.cn/~liweiyu/documents/Algebra,%20Second%20Edition,%20Michael%20Artin.pdf](http://home.ustc.edu.cn/%7Eliweiyu/documents/Algebra,%20Second%20Edition,%20Michael%20Artin.pdf)

Comment: You should attempt problem 4.M.7 first.  It *does not* need Jordan form but will give you insights for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $V$ is finite dimensional, $K_i$ and $U_i$ must also be finite dimensional. If, for instance, the sequence of $K_i$ did not become eventually constant, then there is some sub-sequence $K_{i'}$ that is strictly increasing. This means that the dimensions of $K_{i'}$ are also strictly increasing. However, each of these must also be bounded above by the dimension of $V$. So, we have a strictly increasing set of integers that has an upper bound, a contradiction.

The proof for the $U_i$ is similar, replacing "increasing", "upper", and "above" with their antonyms as appropriate.